# Python Float to Ord values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of float that I need to send over TCP/IP, the protocol is text based so basically I cannot send directly binary.

What Im trying to do is to convert the Float values to 4 Ord

So ex:

""" Initialize the float """

a = 3.14159

""" Final result should be a string containing the 4 Ord, 1 for each byte the of the float value: """

b = "\123\23\22\245"

Anybody can help me with this?

TIA!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `b = b"\123\23\22\245"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("!f",3.14159)
b'@I\x0f\xd0'
```

not sure where you arrived at `"\123\23\22\245"`

If you wish to convert a list of floats

```
>>> a=[3.14159, 2.71828]
>>> struct.pack("!{}f".format(len(a)), *a)
```

will give you a single string. No need for an explicit loop and join

Comment: Ho! the \ between the number is the way the protocol is analyzing bytes value...

So basically I have like 1 float of 3.14159 and I need to convert it into 4 unsigned char value delimited by a \

Comment: Alright just tried your code above:


a = struct.pack("!f",3.14159)

for i in range( len( a ) ):
 print( a[ i ] )

Got it working, now I need to concatenate that into a long string. For this "".join should be the fastest right?

Comment: Another question the !f reverse the byte order, shouldn't it be just f instead?

Comment: `"!f"` uses "network order", so if you are using big endian cpu at one end and little endian cpu at the other end it will still work. You can also use `"<f"` or `">f"` to explicitly choose which of those orderings to use